# Pass std::array as Reference Parameter

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, stdarray

I can pass my array directly, but I need to know how to pass it by reference. I'm using the new std::array with type Element. I've tried several things, but they're not working. I'm not sure how to pass it as a reference. I've messed around and I can't figure this out.

How do I pass a std::array as a reference parameter to avoid copying the entire array?

**How my array is set up:**

```
std::array<Element, 115> Elements =
{{
    /*int aNumber, float awNumber, period_number PERIOD, group_names GROUP_NAME, metal_status METALSTATUS,
    valence_shell Orbital,std::string eName, std::string eSybol);*/
    {},
    {1,     1.00794,        period::PERIOD_ONE,     group::HYDROGEN,        metal::NONMETAL,    shell::S_ORBITAL,   "Hydrogen",     "H"}
}};
```

**Working**

```
void sortByAtomicNumber(std::array<Element, 115> elements, int minimum, int maximum)
{
    int counter = 1;
    for(;minimum < (maximum+1); minimum++)
    {
        std::cout << counter << ".) " << elements[minimum].getElementName() << std::endl;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

**Tried** From: http://gauravpandey.com/wordpress/?p=602 //I haven't learned templates yet...

```
 template<size_t N>
void sortByAtomicNumber(std::array<int, N> const& arr, int maximum, int minimum) {
    int counter = 1;
    for(;minimum < (maximum+1); minimum++)
    {
        std::cout << counter << ".) " << arr[minimum].getElementName() << std::endl;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

**Error from Above**

---

> error: passing 'const value_type {aka const Element}' as 'this' argument of 'std::string > > Element::getElementName()' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

---

Comment: Don't make the reference `const`, because then you won't be able to modify the array...

Comment: @BrianBi I don't need to modify the array; that's why I'm using an array and not a vector.

Comment: Whoops, I misread, sorry.

Comment: @BrianBi, The const reference was the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some errors:

1. In the template `sortByAtomicNumber`, `std::array<int, N>` should be `std::array<Element, N>`.
2. **If you want call a function of a const object, the function must be const.** So your `arr` is const reference, the `void getElementName();` of the `Element` class should be `void getElementName() const;`.
3. **If you want call a non-const function of a object, the object must be non-const.** So `template<size_t N> void sortByAtomicNumber(std::array<int, N> const& arr, int maximum, int minimum) { /* your code */ }` should be `template<size_t N> void sortByAtomicNumber(std::array<Element, N>& arr, int maximum, int minimum) { /* your code */ }`, like @portforwardpodcast said.

**Note:** About the const function of const class, you can see [this article](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/810-const-class-objects-and-member-functions/). Hope that can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It explains a lot. If I would have thought it through then the answer would have been obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
void sortByAtomicNumber(std::array<Element, 115> &elements, int minimum, int maximum)
{
    int counter = 1;
    for(;minimum < (maximum+1); minimum++)
    {
        std::cout << counter << ".) " << elements[minimum].getElementName() << std::endl;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to use a typedef for std::array<Element, 115>

Comment: Sorry. I just updated my question; I had already fixed the type problem and the naming problem.

However when I do, I get this error:  undefined reference to `sortByAtomicNumber(std::array<Element, 115u>, int, int)

Comment: where are you calling this from? it's possible you have a mismatch between your .h and .c file.  Since you haven't posted very much code it will be very hard for me to answer without more information

Comment: Thanks. I compared your code to mine and I thought it was the same... I still had const in my function. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Your function definition looks wrong, the const is in the wrong place:
You gave this definition:

```
template<size_t N>
void sortByAtomicNumber(std::array<int, N> const& arr, int maximum, int minimum)
{
    ...
}
```

It should be:

```
template<size_t N>
void sortByAtomicNumber(const std::array<int, N>& arr, int maximum, int minimum)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Both of your definitions do the same thing, the `const` is moved but the effect is identical. In both the parameter is a const-reference to a `std::array`.